# Flutter Hot Reload causing Navigator.push() to be called disrupting the state of app

Tags: flutter, hot-reload

In my app, I have a landing page where some asynchronous db activities are performed on completion of which, the Home page is where it's navigated to.
The HomePage has numerous other screens in process of creation.
One such screen is a Search page which displays a list of searched items.
The problem is when I am making changes to the Search page and doing hot reload, the Landing page navigates the app to the HomePage again and the state of SearchPage is lost.

How could I implement this without losing state of SearchPage on hot reload?
It would be better if the Database init activity is called only once throughout the app lifecycle and never again until App is restarted.

Comment: Hot reload is helpful in order to help you save the time in repacking and redownloading the app on your device, the state loss is somewhat irrelevant in the actual production scenario...?

Comment: Yes, that's true but I intend to use Hot reload for lowering the development time, for the app would be soon nested many screens deep and if the state isn't preserved then it's a big setback to us.

Comment: I think placing a variable flag indicating if it's called first time to control the navigator might do the trick.

Comment: Post the code of your Landing page, I think I know what your problem is but I cannot be 100% sure

Comment: Placing a flag didn't help but a stateful widget did.

Comment: @AkashGorai Can you answer the question with the actual configuration that worked?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve using the following way probably :

On my LandingPage(the very first screen of app), converting it to a Stateful Widget from a Stateless Widget and doing the following in it -

```
@override
initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => initData(context));
}

initData(){
  //do some async activities
  //After the completion of them
  // Navigate to a desired screen
  Navigator.push(...//)
}
```

This ensured that my `initData` method ran only once throughout until restarting the app and hence no unexpected navigations as well.